How do I get my main discord python file to run other py files?
I am currently running a python API that runs my main.py discord bot file as a subprocess and I don't really want to create another subprocess for each subsequent files that I add to my project. I am currently working on an Analytics.py file that I am running on the side with a test bot while my main bot continues to run, and I want to know how I can run my Analytics.py file in my main.py without creating another subprocess in my API.py.
Any help would be appreciated.

Your two choices are to use subprocess to run the script on its own, or import and run it like any other module.  There's nothing wrong with creating short-lived subprocesses for specific tasks.
